# pyside signal not fired with pyinstaller when communicating between threads

Tags: multithreading, macos, pyside, pyinstaller

I am trying to build an .app for my pyside gui and I'm having a problem when I use signals to communicate between the main thread and another one. When I run the python code, everything works fine. The problem only occurs when I use the .app built from pyinstaller.

The project is quite big, so it's hard to include any code, so i'll try to explain what I'm doing.

My second thread is used to call some functions from a dylib which controls our devices. The main thread uses a callback to tell the dylib to stop what it's doing. The dylib calls the callback function in a loop, and stops if the value returned from the main thread is different than 0.

As I mentioned, when I run the Python code (under Windows, Ubuntu, Mac), it works perfectly. But when using the .app built with pyinstaller, it looks like the signal is not sent from the main thread.  While debugging, I printed stuff and eventually saw that the dylib doesn't receive the returned value from the callback. The dylib does use the callback, and I can see the expected data in the main thread.

So why would the signal not be fired with frozen python code?
Has anybody ever encounter a similar problem?
If you could give me some debugging advices, it would be really helpful?

**EDIT**

I managed to write a !little code which reproduces the problem. When I run the python code, pressing "ok" followed by "Cancel" sets the message "DLL got the value" in the widget. When freezing the code with Pyinstaller, under mac, the message never gets set on the widget. On Windows 7, everything is fine.

**EDIT**

Actually, no need for the shared library to cause the problem. The problem occurs only with the Python code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the Python code:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide.QtCore import QThread, Signal, QObject

def functionInDLL(callback):
    return_value = 0
    while (return_value == 0):
        return_value = callback(2)


class MyThread(QThread):
    str_signal = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.return_value = 0

    def returnValueToDll(self, data=0):
        return self.return_value 

    def run(self):
        if functionInDLL(self.returnValueToDll) == 42:
            print"DLL got the value."
            self.str_signal.emit("DLL got the value.")
        else:
            print"DLL did not get the value."
            self.str_signal.emit("DLL did not get the value.")
        self.exec_()         

    def setValueSentToDll(self, data):
        self.return_value = data



class MainThreadClass(QObject):
    int_signal = Signal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainThreadClass, self).__init__()
        self.test_thread = MyThread()
        self.int_signal.connect(self.test_thread.setValueSentToDll)

    def startMyThread(self):
        self.test_thread.start()

    def sendStopValueToDLL(self):
        self.int_signal.emit(42)          



class MyGUI(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyGUI, self).__init__()
        self.text_information = QtGui.QLabel(text="No started yet...")
        self.dll_information = QtGui.QLabel(text="")
        self.ok_button = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
        self.cancel_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        self.close_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Close")
        label_hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.ok_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.cancel_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.close_button)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        label_hbox.addWidget(self.text_information)
        label_hbox.addWidget(self.dll_information)
        vbox.addLayout(label_hbox)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.ok_button.clicked.connect(self.onOk)
        self.cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.onCancel)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.onClose)
        self.show()
        self.main_thread = MainThreadClass()
        self.main_thread.test_thread.str_signal.connect(lambda data: self.setDllStatusOnWidget(data))


    def onOk(self):
        self.main_thread.startMyThread()    
        self.text_information.setText("Started")
        self.dll_information.setText("")

    def onCancel(self):
        self.main_thread.sendStopValueToDLL()
        self.text_information.setText("Canceled")

    def onClose(self):
        self.main_thread.test_thread.exit()   
        self.close()

    def setDllStatusOnWidget(self, text=""):
        self.dll_information.setText(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyGUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks
Using Python2.7, Mac Pro Yosemite

Comment: Is the issue just when built on OS X or also when built on windows and linux? I think this also really needs a [MCVE] (which I know is hard, but if it's a bug with PyInstaller, you will need it to get the bug fixed)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will see what I can do for the code example. As for Windows and Linux I didn't use pyinstaller. I used it on Mac because I could not find a way to make an app bundle which would call my Python script. I'm running late on my project, but you are right, I have to try this on Windows and Linux to see if it's a bug with pyinstaller.

Comment: I wrote a minimal example and could not reproduce the problem. When the code is frozen, the signal gets emitted properly. So I must be doing something which prevents the signal to be emitted. The search continues...

Comment: ...but it seems that freezing my project under windows does cause the problem.

Comment: Hey there. I'm using PyInstaller, Windows, and PySide together, and I happen to be on the PyInstaller dev team. If you can post your minimal example to the [PyInstaller issue tracker](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues), I'll see what I can do about it. FWIW, I'm using cross-thread signals in my own program to swap OpenGL buffers on a second thread and haven't seen any problems.

Comment: Hi, i'm currently trying to come up with a "short" code to reproduce the problem. I will post it as soon as I can. So far the problem only occurs on Mac. ...to be continued

Comment: Hope this example helps. I don't know if i'm missing something or if there is a problem somewhere in pyinstaller. If it is a problem in pyinstaller, i will post the example. but i'm not sure yet. It may be the way i wrote my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to codewarrior, my bug was solved.
When I replaced the line:

```
self.main_thread.test_thread.str_signal.connect(lambda data: self.setDllStatusOnWidget(data))
```

by this line, removing the lambda:

```
self.main_thread.test_thread.str_signal.connect(self.setDllStatusOnWidget)
```

See the link for more details. I hope this can help other people.
[pyinstaller_issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1657)